# Rails generates number instead of name OR I get undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This worked at some point but I can't figure out what went wrong or how to correct course.

I'm getting the following on my index page:
NoMethodError in Admin::Locations#index undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

It's coming from the following:

```
<tbody>
   <% @locations.each do |location| %>
   <tr>
     <td><%= location.name %></td>
     <td><%= location.state %></td>
     <td><%= location.region.name %></td>
   </tr>
   <% end %>
 </tbody>
```

Specifically the location.region.name. My locations controller looks like:

```
class Admin::LocationsController < Admin::ApplicationController
 belongs_to_app :locations
 add_breadcrumb 'Locations', :admin_locations_path
 before_action :load_location, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def index
  @locations = Location.ordered.paginate(page: params[:page])
  @locations = @locations.search(params[:search]) if params[:search]
  respond_with @locations
end

def show
  respond_with @location
end

def new
  @location = Location.new
  respond_with @location
end

def create
  @location = Location.new(location_params)
  flash[:notice] = 'Location created successfully' if @location.save
  respond_with @location, location: admin_locations_path
end

def edit
  respond_with @location
end

def update
  flash[:notice] = 'Location updated successfully' if @location.update_attributes(location_params)
  respond_with @location, location: admin_locations_path
end

def destroy
  flash[:notice] = 'Location deleted successfully' if @location.destroy
  respond_with @location, location: admin_locations_path
end

private

def load_location
  @location = Location.find_by!(id: params[:id])
end

def location_params
  params.require(:location).permit(:name, :hours_operation, :abbreviation, :address_1, :address_2, :city, :state,
  :postal_code, :phone, :fax, :region, :region_id)
end
end
```

Now if I change `location.region.name` to `location.region`, it will actually generate something like

```
#<Region:0x0005223ac5>
```

Really there's only one region being applied so I'm at a loss.

Comment: "This worked at some point but I can't figure out what went wrong" - before I read any further: If you use git (or another version control system), simply go back to last known working commit and try again. If you don't use version control, drop everything and learn basics _now_. It's an essential tool of a modern developer.

Comment: What do you mean, "if I change `location.region.name`"?

Comment: I actually did go back and can't discern any changes that caused this. It's incredibly frustrating. I did see one small change in my controller but I updated that and still a problem.

Comment: If I use location.region I get the generation. If I use location.region.name I get the error. I updated the question.

Comment: Ah, but if you use simply use `location.region`, do you have that for __all__ locations? I bet you 10$ that there's at least one location without this. (meaning that this location's region is `nil`. Also meaning that it's a data problem and rolling code back likely wouldn't help)

Comment: You would get $10. I applied a region to it and sure enough it works. Now to figure out how to fix this for when there's a blank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now if I change location.region.name to location.region, it will actually generate something like
>
> ```
> #<Region:0x0005223ac5>
> ```

Ah, but if you use simply use `location.region`, do you have that for all locations? I bet you $10 that there's at least one location without this. (meaning that this location's region is `nil`. Also meaning that it's a data problem and rolling code back likely wouldn't help)

A quick fix would be to do what @Kwstas suggests. Or this one (called "safe navigation operator" or "lonely operator"):

```
location.region&.name
```

But this is just a band-aid. If regions are mandatory for all locations, I'd look into ways of ensuring that. Maybe put some activerecord validations in place, or something.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace it to:

```
location.region.try(:name)
```